# Python: I want from a program to ask me only once for input

Tags: python

I'm practicing with a simple roulette program. At this moment, I have a problem with balance input(), if I put it outside the function, the function betting() doesn't recognize it. But, if I put it inside, the function, the program asks me again to input the amount of money and it overwrites the amount of money after the bet.

How to avoid that, so the program asks me only once for input? This is my code:

```
import random

def betting():
balance = float(input("How much money do you have? $"))
your_number = int(input("Choose the number between 0 and 36, including these: "))
if your_number < 0 or your_number > 36:
    print("Wrong input, try again!")
    betting()
else:
    bet = float(input("Place your bet: "))
while balance > 0:
    if bet > balance:
        print("You don't have enough money! Place your bet again!")
        betting()
    else:
        number = random.randint(0,36)
    print(f"Your number is {your_number} and roulette's number is {number}.")
    if number == your_number:
        balance = balance + bet*37
        print(f"You won! Now you have ${balance}!")
    else:
        balance = balance - bet
        print(f"You lost! Now you have ${balance}!")
    betting()
else:
    print("You don't have more money! Goodbye!")
    quit()

def choice():
choice = str(input("Y/N "))
if choice.lower() == "y":
    betting()
elif choice.lower() == "n":
    print("Goodbye!")
    quit()
else:
    print("Wrong input, try again!")
    choice()

print("Welcome to the Grand Casino! Do you want to play roulette?")
choice()
```

Comment: Your indentation is clearly wrong, but what’s less clear is how this ought to be indented. Don’t make us guess; please [edit] to fix this. (On the desktop version of this site, paste your program, select it, and type ctrl-K to properly format it as code.)

Comment: The recursive calls (where `betting` calls itself) are problematic; recall that the called function will `return` at some point, and then the code in the caller continues just after the call. The usual solution is to instead have a `while True:` loop or similar, and then leaving the loop with `break` (or the entire function with `return`) when the user has supplied correct input.

Comment: Your choice function is poorly written: you are using a recursive call to repeat the question, which will probably work for you but in other looping situations it could result in a genuine stack overflow.  Better to use a while loop.

Answer (score 2):

Pass the balance as a function parameter to `betting()`. Then ask once in the `choice()` function

```
import random

def betting(balance):
    your_number = int(input("Choose the number between 0 and 36, including these: "))
    if your_number < 0 or your_number > 36:
        print("Wrong input, try again!")
        return your_number
    else:
        bet = float(input("Place your bet: "))
    while balance > 0:
        if bet > balance:
            print("You don't have enough money! Place your bet again!")
            betting(balance)
        else:
            number = random.randint(0,36)
        print(f"Your number is {your_number} and roulette's number is {number}.")
        if number == your_number:
            balance = balance + bet*37
            print(f"You won! Now you have ${balance}!")
        else:
            balance = balance - bet
            print(f"You lost! Now you have ${balance}!")
        betting(balance)
    else:
        print("You don't have more money! Goodbye!")
        quit()

def choice():
    choice = str(input("Y/N "))
    if choice.lower() == "y":
        balance = float(input("How much money do you have? $"))
        betting(balance)
    elif choice.lower() == "n":
        print("Goodbye!")
        quit()
    else:
        print("Wrong input, try again!")
        choice()

print("Welcome to the Grand Casino! Do you want to play roulette?")
choice()
```

Comment: This one works, ty!

Answer (score 1):

You can ask for both at the same time and split the given string:

```
inp = input("State how much money you have and a number between 0 and 36 inclusive, separated by space: ")
bal, num = inp.split()
```

Answer (score 0):

Python allocate a variable in the closest namespace.
This mean that balance is allocated in 'betting' namespace and will not be known outside 'betting'.
What you need is a global variable.
'global' mean that the variable must be allocated in the embracing namespace.

```
def betting():
  global balance
  print( balance)

def choice():
  global balance
  sel = input( ...)
  if sel.lower() == 'y':
    balance = int( input(">"))
    betting()

choice()
```

Please note that you used 'choice' for 2 purposes. It's a function but it is also a variable. While it is possible, it is considered a bad habit.